# Поиск данных через RowFilter в dataGridView по всем столбцам

Tags: c#, база-данных, datagridview

Есть таблица authors со столбцами fio, count, url. Все данные загружаются в datagridview (столбец с ID тоже, но он не отображается на форме).
Обычно поиск в гриде делал циклом, пробегая по строкам. Недавно узнал про то, что есть такая штука, как RowFilter.
Сделал следующим образом:

```
(author.dgvAuthor.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Convert([{0}], 'System.String') LIKE '%{1}%'", "count", searchText.Text);
```

В принципе, все работает так, как надо. Но можно ли сделать, чтобы поиск автоматически работал по всем столбцам таблицы, а не только по тем, что я явно укажу? Про вариант с указанием столбцов через OR я знаю, но интересует можно ли обойтись без такого. 
Дело в том, что у меня еще 9 таблиц и для каждой надо сделать поиск. Подумал, что может есть более короткий вариант кода, чем писать для каждой таблицы такие фильтры.

Comment: На сколько я понял данные в таблице из Базы данных так почему бы вам не делать запрос в базу по вашим параметрам а потом результат поиска передавать в `author.dgvAuthor.DataSource =`

Comment: @OXYGEN так разве будет не одно и то же? Там же все равно придется указать столбцы, в которых осуществляется поиск.

Comment: во всех случаях результат будет одним и тем же, запрос в базу отработает быстрее, более того запрос можно сделать более универсальным или создать процедуру в базе которую сможете дергать и не менять исходный код в случаи изменений, это дело вкуса.